# Iterate through a Java RDD by row

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I would like to iterate through an RDD of strings and "do something" to each string. The output should be `double[][]`. Here is an example with a for loop. I understand I need to use (I think) the `foreach` function for Java RDDs. However, I have no idea how to understand the syntax. Documentation is not particularly helpful. I do not have Java 8.

Here is an example of what I would like to do if I could use a regular `for` loop.

```
public class PCA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("PCA Example");
        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);

        RDD<String> data = sc.textFile("my/directory/my/dataset.txt", 0);

        // here is the "type" of code I would like to execute
        // 30 because I have 30 variables
        double[][] vals = new double[data.count()][30];

        double[] temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.count(); i++) {
            temp = splitStringtoDoubles(data[i]);
            vals[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    private static double[] splitStringtoDoubles(String s) {
        String[] splitVals = s.split("\\t");
        Double[] vals = new Double[splitVals.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < splitVals.length; i++) {
            vals[i] = Double.parseDouble(splitVals[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

I understand that `foreach` seems to require a function that has a void return type. Not sure how to work with that. Here is what I have attempted so far (obviously the syntax is wrong):

```
    double[][] matrix = new double[data.count()][30];
    foreach(String s : data) {
        String[] splitvals = s.split("\\t");
        double[] vals = Double.parseDouble(splitvals);
        matrix[s] = vals; 
    }
```

Comment: Since you want a return type, rather than void, you should use `map` instead of `foreach` and return a new matrix for each string.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example, @mattinbits? As I said, I'm not familiar with Spark Java and most of the examples of map I have seen have been in java 8 with lambda functions, which I can't use.

Comment: I could provide one in Scala but not Java the answer below from @Balduz looks good though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *mattinbits* said in the comments, you want a `map` instead of a `foreach`, since you want to return values. What a `map` does basically is to transform your data: for each row of your RDD you perform an operation and return one value for each row. What you need can be achieved like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

...

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("PCA Example");
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);

JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("clean-sl-mix-with-labels.txt",0).toJavaRDD();
JavaRDD<double[]> whatYouWantRdd = data.map(new Function<String, double[]>() {
    @Override
    public double[] call(String row) throws Exception {
        return splitStringtoDoubles(row);
    }

    private double[] splitStringtoDoubles(String s) {
        String[] splitVals = s.split("\\t");
        Double[] vals = new Double[splitVals.length];
        for(int i=0; i < splitVals.length; i++) {
            vals[i] = Double.parseDouble(splitVals[i]);
        }
        return vals;
    }
});

List<double[]> whatYouWant = whatYouWantRdd.collect();
```

So that you know how Spark works, you perform actions or transformations on your RDD. For instance, here we are transforming our RDD using a `map` function. You need to create this function yourself, this time with an anonymous `org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function` which forces you to override the method `call`, where you receive a row of your RDD and return a value.

Comment: Collect action is not recommended action since it pulls all the data to driver program which is highly expensive.

Answer (score 4):

Just because it's interesting to compare the verboseness of the Java vs Scala API for Spark, here's a Scala version:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

class example extends App {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Spark example")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val inputData = List(
    "1.2\t2.7\t3.8",
    "4.3\t5.1\t6.3"
  )

  val inputRDD = sc.parallelize(inputData)
  val arrayOfDoubleRDD = inputRDD.map(_.split("\t").map(_.toDouble))
}
```

Comment: Can't agree with you more that Scala is better. I've done some work in Python for Spark and it's amazing how easy it is to use functions like `map`. Alas, I have to use Java for this case.

Comment: I too prefer Scala for Spark, as Java is **much** more verbose... Unfortunately my Scala skills are nonexistent :(